# Cplex in Python - Student Licence

Tags: python, cplex, pulp

I downloaded the cplex studio 12.8 with a student licence and try to connect it with pulp in python. Even though there are some people on stack that also had problems with setting cplex up in python, the answers could not help me. My cplex sub-directories only include folders that are called 'example'. No setup.py file is included. This is how the directories look like:

[image: Folder in CPLEX_Studio128]

And within the python directory:

[image: Folder in Python directory]

Within the examples file there are only example problems.

Did I install Cplex studio correctly? How can I setup cplex within pulp?

Comment: You are right! Thanks!

Comment: I've removed my comment and posted it below as an answer. It appears that what I suspected was wrong was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the full path of the `examples` directory you mentioned at the end? I suspect this is under your user directory (the installer makes a copy of the examples in this location for your convenience). The `setup.py` file is installed in the version specific sub-directories (i.e., directories named `2.7`, `3.5`, and `3.6`) under the following location by default: `C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\python`.

Comment: Peter: If you don't mind, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that others can see that the question has been resolved.